# store the data that comes from backend into useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a project and within this project I use TypeScript and React, but I encountered a problem that I want to store the response coming from the backend and put it in "setDataTraining" but the problem is that nothing is stored within this variable "dataTraining"

How can i solve this problem?

this is Response that comes from backend.

[image]

I tried using the following instruction:

```
committeeData?.items
```

And store it in the variable "dataTraining", but it didn't recognize the value of items even though it came from the backend.

index.tsx:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FunctionComponent, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Check } from 'react-feather';
import { useMutation, useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import caseServeice from '../../../api/nuclearMedicineApi/services/Case';
import {
    AuthContext,
    IAuthContext,
} from '../../../contexts/auth-context';
import Scaffold from '../../common/scaffold';
import { committeeRequestColumns } from './data';
import { committeeRequestFilters } from './filters';
import committeeRequest from '../../../api/nuclearMedicineApi/services/CommitteeRequests';
import { notify } from '../../common/notification';

interface CommitteeRequestPageProps { }

const CommitteeRequestPage: FunctionComponent<CommitteeRequestPageProps> = () => {
    const auth = useContext<IAuthContext>(AuthContext);

    let committeeColumns = committeeRequestColumns;
    committeeColumns = auth.userData?.roleNames?.some(
        (role) => role === 'DOCTOR',
    )
        ? committeeColumns.filter(
            (item) => item.dataSelector !== 'supervisoryDoctor',
        )
        : committeeColumns;

        const approveCommitteeRequestNotification = () => {
            // onSuccess: (data) => {
            notify('success', 'ok', 'approveCommitteeRequest');
            // },
        };

        const [dataTraining, setDataTraining] = useState({})
        const getDataFromBackend = async(waitingListId: any) =>{
            console.log('number: ', waitingListId, typeof(waitingListId)); 
            let dataPat = await committeeRequest.approveCommitteeRequest(waitingListId); 
            console.log('data training: ', dataTraining)
            console.log('getDataApprove: ', dataPat); 
            return dataPat; 
        }

       
        const getAllCommitteeData = async() => {
            let committeeData = await committeeRequest.comitteeRequestGetAll();
            setDataTraining(committeeData);
            console.log('committee Data Response: ', committeeData);
            console.log('data training: ', dataTraining); 
            return committeeData; 
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            getAllCommitteeData();
            setDataTraining((v) => v)
            console.log('data training outside: ', dataTraining)}, [dataTraining])


        // console.log('data training outside: ', dataTraining); 


        // useEffect(() => {
        //     committeeRequest.comitteeRequestGetAll()
        // }, []);


    return (
        <>
            <Scaffold
                getAllFunc={getAllCommitteeData}
                tableColumns={committeeColumns}
                filterColumns={committeeRequestFilters}
                getAllParams={{ MaxResultCount: 1000 }}
                create={false}
                fullWidthFrom
                dataName='committeeRequest'
                formType='full'
                update={false}
                restrictedActions={{ update: false }}
                // documentaionId={1}
                customCreateAction={() => {
                    // navigate('/auth/patient/create');
                } }
                customActions={[
                    {
                        Icon: <Check className='icon-button-table' />,
                        cb: (id) => {
                            console.log('iddddd: ', id)
                            let waitingListId = +id; 
                            console.log('idfgdg: ', waitingListId, typeof(waitingListId));
                            // setWaitingNumberId(waitingListId)
                            getDataFromBackend(waitingListId)
                            // committeeRequest.comitteeRequestGetAll()
                            // committeeRequest.approveCommitteeRequest(waitingListId)
                            // console.log('const a: ', a);
                            approveCommitteeRequestNotification()
                            
                        },
                        tooltip: 'Approve',
                    },
                ]}
                customOnRowClick={(row) => { } }
                FormSubmitMapper={(data) => data}
                mainPermissionName='Patient'
                tableDataMapper={(data) => {
                    return data?.map((row: any) => {
                        return {
                            ...row,
                            patient: row.patient?.label,
                            supervisoryDoctor: row.supervisoryDoctor?.label, 
                            topographyIndex: row.topographyIndex?.label, 
                            machine: row.machine?.label,

                        };
                    });
                } } createFunc={function (data: any): Promise<any> {
                    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
                } } updateFunc={function (data: any): Promise<any> {
                    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
                } } getFunc={function (data: any): Promise<any> {
                    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
                } } deleteFunc={function (data: any): Promise<any> {
                    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
                } }            />
        </>
    );
};

export default CommitteeRequestPage;
```

Comment: What does the console.log statement print? Is the committeeData correct? Please note state updates are not reflected immediately so you cant console.log to see the updated value in the state variable

Comment: Can you please show us what you tried? I don't see any code, that tries to write something to `dataTraining`.

Comment: the picture is the console, it return right data from backend @Daniel Smith

Comment: based on picture, i tried to put setDataTraining(committeeData?.items) @Garuno

Comment: Your code is working correctly, please use the useEffect hook i have mentioned below to see the updated state value. In react state updates are not reflected immediately.

Comment: how can i use useEffect in this state? @Daniel Smith

Comment: I have added the code below as an answer. Try copy pasting it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably working fine. You might have been confused by the
console.log('data training: ', dataTraining) part.

If you want to see updated state values use a useEffect hook. You cannot use console.log to get the latest state value.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FunctionComponent, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Check } from 'react-feather';
import { useMutation, useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import caseServeice from '../../../api/nuclearMedicineApi/services/Case';
import {
    AuthContext,
    IAuthContext,
} from '../../../contexts/auth-context';
import Scaffold from '../../common/scaffold';
import { committeeRequestColumns } from './data';
import { committeeRequestFilters } from './filters';
import committeeRequest from '../../../api/nuclearMedicineApi/services/CommitteeRequests';
import { notify } from '../../common/notification';

interface CommitteeRequestPageProps { }

const CommitteeRequestPage: FunctionComponent<CommitteeRequestPageProps> = () => {
    const auth = useContext<IAuthContext>(AuthContext);

    let committeeColumns = committeeRequestColumns;
    committeeColumns = auth.userData?.roleNames?.some(
        (role) => role === 'DOCTOR',
    )
        ? committeeColumns.filter(
            (item) => item.dataSelector !== 'supervisoryDoctor',
        )
        : committeeColumns;

        const approveCommitteeRequestNotification = () => {
            // onSuccess: (data) => {
            notify('success', 'ok', 'approveCommitteeRequest');
            // },
        };

        const [dataTraining, setDataTraining] = useState({})
        const getDataFromBackend = async(waitingListId: any) =>{
            console.log('number: ', waitingListId, typeof(waitingListId)); 
            let dataPat = await committeeRequest.approveCommitteeRequest(waitingListId); 
            console.log('data training: ', dataTraining)
            console.log('getDataApprove: ', dataPat); 
            return dataPat; 
        }

       
        const getAllCommitteeData = async() => {
            let committeeData = await committeeRequest.comitteeRequestGetAll();
            setDataTraining(committeeData);
            console.log('committee Data Response: ', committeeData);
            console.log('data training: ', dataTraining); 
            return committeeData; 
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            getAllCommitteeData();
            console.log('data training outside: ', dataTraining)}, [])




    return (
        <>
            <Scaffold
                getAllFunc={getAllCommitteeData}
                tableColumns={committeeColumns}
                filterColumns={committeeRequestFilters}
                getAllParams={{ MaxResultCount: 1000 }}
                create={false}
                fullWidthFrom
                dataName='committeeRequest'
                formType='full'
                update={false}
                restrictedActions={{ update: false }}
                // documentaionId={1}
                customCreateAction={() => {
                    // navigate('/auth/patient/create');
                } }
                customActions={[
                    {
                        Icon: <Check className='icon-button-table' />,
                        cb: (id) => {
                            console.log('iddddd: ', id)
                            let waitingListId = +id; 
                            console.log('idfgdg: ', waitingListId, typeof(waitingListId));
                            // setWaitingNumberId(waitingListId)
                            getDataFromBackend(waitingListId)
                            // committeeRequest.comitteeRequestGetAll()
                            // committeeRequest.approveCommitteeRequest(waitingListId)
                            // console.log('const a: ', a);
                            approveCommitteeRequestNotification()
                            
                        },
                        tooltip: 'Approve',
                    },
                ]}
                customOnRowClick={(row) => { } }
                FormSubmitMapper={(data) => data}
                mainPermissionName='Patient'
                tableDataMapper={(data) => {
                    return data?.map((row: any) => {
                        return {
                            ...row,
                            patient: row.patient?.label,
                            supervisoryDoctor: row.supervisoryDoctor?.label, 
                            topographyIndex: row.topographyIndex?.label, 
                            machine: row.machine?.label,

                        };
                    });
                } } createFunc={function (data: any): Promise<any> {
                    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
                } } updateFunc={function (data: any): Promise<any> {
                    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
                } } getFunc={function (data: any): Promise<any> {
                    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
                } } deleteFunc={function (data: any): Promise<any> {
                    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
                } }            />
        </>
    );
};
export default CommitteeRequestPage;
```

Add this code and see the updated state value

Comment: nothing happen, the same error, the base problem is for the type of useState, i need to display items and store them inside "dataTraining" but i can't

Comment: i get this error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Comment: @HibaYoussef Please share the updated code you are using here so we can help you out

Comment: i update my post @Daniel Smith

Comment: Remove the setDatatraining in the useEffect and see that will fix it.

Comment: i remove it but it enter in infinit loop @Daniel Smith

Comment: Can you try again with the code i have posted, i missed one thing in the useEffect hook, hopefully this should work fine for you

Comment: it still same @Daniel Smith

Comment: If you can upload your complete codebase somewhere and share it, i can try to find a fix for it

Answer (score 0):

logging dataTraining right after setting will always log null, because dataTraining is filled **after** the (re)render of the screen, this needs some time.

To log dataTraining eventually you can do something like:

```
dataTraining && console.log(dataTraining);
```

Comment: can u edit my code please?